# Swift: How to make a new indexPath for the extra keys of a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I want the iteration of a dictionary to happen for all keys in it, not just for one in the indexPath.row

```
struct Whatever {
   var title: String
   var tag: [String:String?]?
}

var cases = [
     Whatever(title: "Name1", tag: ["key1": "value1", "key2":"value2"]),
     Whatever(title: "Name2", tag: ["key3": "value3"]
]
```

Later in the ViewController:

```
let arrayCases = cases[indexPath.row]
let caseTag = arrayCases.tag!

for key in caseTag.keys {
    cell.titleLabel?.text = key
    //the magic stops somewhere here

}

for value in caseTag.values {
    if value != nil {
        cell.txt.text = value
    } else {
        cell.txt.text = arrayCases.title
    }
}
```

Could you tell me how to make a new indexPath.row for the second tag? As if it's a separate insurance of 'Whatever'?
Second question - why does it show after each build a different tag - sometimes it's "tag1", other times it's "tag2"?
Thank you!

Comment: How do you get indexPath.row ? and what do you mean by making a new indexPath.row ?

Comment: Firstly, your dictionary should probably be [String:String]; an optional value doesn't make a lot of sense. Second, dictionaries are unordered, so it is not defined which order you will get when iterating over the keys.  Third you can't make a new row like that; the number of rows is determined by the value you return from `numberOfRows`. You might want to use a collectionview in each table row to display the tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard table view (without sections) each item in the data source represents **one** row. You cannot simply *make a new indexPath.row*.

You have two options:

1. Use sections: One `Whatever` is one ***section***, the `title` is the header, each `tag` is one ***row*** (see code below)
2. Concatenate the tag keys and values

   ```
   cell.titleLabel?.text = caseTag.keys.joined(separator: ", ") 

   cell.txt.text = caseTag.values.joined(separator: ", ")
   ```

---

Regarding *second question*: Dictionaries are unordered, there is no order. If you need a specific order use another struct `Tag` and make `tags` an array for example

```
struct Whatever {
    let title: String
    let tags: [Tag]
}

struct Tag {
    let key, value : String
}

let cases = [
    Whatever(title: "Name1", tags: [Tag(key: "key1", value: "value1"), Tag(key: "key2", value: "value2")]),
    Whatever(title: "Name2", tags: [Tag(key: "key3", value: "value3"), Tag(key: "key4", value: "value4")])
]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let case = cases[section]
    return case.title
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

...

    let section = cases[indexPath.section]
    let case = section.tags[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel?.text = case.key
    cell.txt.text = case.value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add two calculated properties to your struct that returns a list of tag keys and values respectively to make the rest of the code cleaner.

```
var allTagKeys: String {
    if let keys = tag?.keys {
        return keys.sorted().joined(separator: ", ")
    }
    return ""
}

var allTagValues: String {
    if let values = tag?.compactMap({ $0.value }) {
        return values.joined(separator: ", ")
    }       
    return ""
}
```

}

Note that I added sorting to the keys, not sure you want that.